# Signing user through google login (firebase and javascript )

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to log the user in using firebase, google, and javascript

Code

```
   responseGoogle(googleUser) {
        console.log('Google Auth Response', googleUser);
        // We need to register an Observer on Firebase Auth to make sure auth is initialized.
        var unsubscribe = app.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser => {
            unsubscribe();
            // Check if we are already signed-in Firebase with the correct user.
            if (!this.isUserEqual(googleUser, firebaseUser)) {
                // Build Firebase credential with the Google ID token.
                var credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
                    googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token);
                // Sign in with credential from the Google user.
                app.auth().signInWithCredential(credential).catch(error => {
                    // Handle Errors here.
                    var errorCode = error.code;
                    var errorMessage = error.message;
                    // The email of the user's account used.
                    var email = error.email;
                    // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
                    var credential = error.credential;
                    this.setState({error: errorMessage})
                }).then ( () => {
                    const csrfToken = Utils.getCookie('csrfToken');
                    var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token
                    var access_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().access_token
                    // send id_token to nodejs
                })
            } else {
                console.log('User already signed-in Firebase.');
                console.log('test5');
                this.setState({error: "You are already signed in."});
            }
        });
    }

        isUserEqual (googleUser, firebaseUser) {
            if (firebaseUser) {
                var providerData = firebaseUser.providerData;
                for (var i = 0; i < providerData.length; i++) {
                    if (providerData[i].providerId === firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID &&
                        providerData[i].uid === googleUser.getBasicProfile().getId()) {
                        // We don't need to reauth the Firebase connection.
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

I keep getting errors like bad access token or bad signature when sending the access token to nodejs backend. Can someone please help?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish here.  The auth state listener triggers in response to the user signing in or out.  It doesn't make sense to me to sign in the user (again?) if they just signed in or out.

Comment: I'm trying to get google sign in to work on reactjs and nodejs. It's not working. Can you help please?

Comment: @DougStevenson see edited question